# How can I protect my asp.net web api? I can not understand the template well

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am new to ASP.NET MVC. Now all I know is how to add the *authorize* attribute to my controller or action.

How can I check if I have the access, and if not, how do I sign up and log in?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, can you add some code to clarify your problem? Right now your question is too broad to answer, and possibly will be closed by moderators because of that.

Comment: I'm just can not write any code for this area. my demand is that, users use mobile client such as iPhone to read and write data but how I protect it? I mean who have the right to read and who can write.

Comment: I corrected some English grammar and inserted some whitespace to make the question pop out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are doing is straight forward enough. Any API over HTTP needs a simple authentication mechanism. This typically involves an authentication cookie you set when the user logs on.

The trick is to read this authentication cookie from the HTTP response. Then, make sure it gets included in every request after this. The `Authorize` attribute takes care of the rest.

To clarify, authentication is about *who*. Once you authenticate a user, you still need to figure out *what* level of access is needed through authorization.